# Delete local .git folder and start from scratch

Tags: git

I have deleted a lot of files on my local master branch and then was trying to update remote master branch but after reaching 63% I was getting objects writing error from git and it hanged also there was a high CPU utilisation.

Now I would like to empty the remote master branch or is it possible to delete the  .git folder from the project directory and start from scratch.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy for you. If you have deleted .git folder from local repo. Just write command

```
git init
```

it will again create the `.git` folder for you. And it is as good as creating a new repo.

post that use command

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git

git pull

git add .

git commit -m "Some Text Here"

git push origin master
```

You are done.

Comment: What if remote master is partially updated and corrupted? The idea is good but don't trash your old local before you init the new one, just in case :-)

Comment: Thanks Kunal. It worked. I took a backup of old git folder by chance if I have to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is not fully clear to me. What do you mean with 'empty the remote master branch'?

- If you delete your local `.git` folder, all local git history will be gone. Assuming you didn't clone the repository on a different machine too, the single source of truth will be the remote repository. You could then again clone the repository.
- If you want to revert your latest commit on remote master, there's `git reset`. It's best to create a new branch from master and perform all required actions there until you're happy. Then merge it back to master.
- If you want to push your local version to a new remote, you can add a new remote in `./git/config` and push any local branch accordingly using `git push <remote> <branch>`

Please clarify your question if I got you wrong.